# How to get ' logs' of the queries in dgraph-orm

Tags: node.js, logging, orm, dgraph

The earlier version of **dgraph-orm** provided logging of the queries by default but after the latest update it has been turned off. So is there any way to turn on the logging. I need to debug and find out if the queries being fired are correct.

This is what I have tried:

```
    dgraph.connect(config.database.dgraph);
    dgraph.logging((a)=>console.log(a));
```

**The version that I am using is 1.2.2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked any its working fine, find the snippet below

```
import dgraph from 'dgraph-orm';

// you can pass your logger function here
dgraph.logging(console.log);
```